# Custom Button Permission to selected Users in a Profile

Tags: custom-button, profile, permission-sets

I have created a Custom Button on Lead Object, and placed it on the Page Layout associated with a particular Lead RecordType.  This Page is assigned to all the users in the Profile.

**I want to limit the visibility of the button to only selected Users in a Profile, and not all users**

I understand permission to Custom Button can only be assigned at Profile level.

**Is there any other way to make the button visible to selected users only?**

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think, that is possible by means of standard classic functionality without a custom VF page. I recommend you to switch to LEX and use [Dynamic Actions](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_lex_dynamic_actions_highlights_panel.htm&type=5&release=228)

Comment: @OleksandrBerehovskyi You know, that should be an answer, right?

Comment: @sfdcfox this is fixed, sir :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't think, that it is possible to accomplish by means of standard classic functionality without a custom VF page, or any other custom development.

On the other hand, it is possible to implement this requirement in Lightning Experience.

Use [Dynamic Actions](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_lex_dynamic_actions_highlights_panel.htm&type=5&release=228). In Winer'21 it is GA for custom objects for a Desktop and Beta for mobile, and beta for standard objects

Using this feature you can individually for each action set action visibility.